# Basic variables in a linear program

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I have a small size linear program with restrictions Ax<=b and x>=0. To solve it I've been using the Python library scipy.optimize.linprog.
From my n variables, I need to know which ones form the basis.

I searched a lot and couldn't find a way for this. I also tried the Pulp library without success.
I'm interested in degenerate instances, so looking for positive variables is not enough; it is likely that some zero variable is basic.

Do you know a way to get this information? I can use any library, but it has to be on Python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is almost no LP solver that does not return arrays/vectors containing the basis status of each variable and each row (or slack). Unfortunately `scipy.optimize.linprog` is the exception. I am sure if you look at the source you can locate basis status arrays. Pulp is not a solver but a modeling tool. I am not sure what solution info Pulp provides. But you can always generate an MPS file with PULP and feed that in any LP solver.

If the solution is non-degenerate you can do something like

```
   x(j)>0  => basic
   x(j)=0  => non-basic
   s(i)>0  => slack is basic
   s(i)=0  => slack is non-basic
```

However if the solution is degenerate we have some basic variables/slacks with value zero.